# .NET Windows service executes batch file from system32 folder not install folder

Tags: c#, .net, service, directory, aruba

The code for the service is as follows

```
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); // Declare New Process

            var arguments =
                String.Format("--ip {0}  --user {1} --passwd {2} --guest {3} --gpasswd {4} --action {5}",
                              controllerIPAddress, controllerUsername, controllerPassword, username, password, action);

            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Netspot\\ControllerInterfaceService\\batchfile.bat";

            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
```

I have a windows service that runs a dos script that calls a WGET command, all good, but I need to create and delete a temp folder using the batch script.

The problem I have is that the service is mapping the path to

```
  c:\windows\system32
```

instead of

```
  C:\\Program Files\\Netspot\\ControllerInterfaceService\\
```

This works fine within a test harness.

Any ideas on why the service uses the  system32 folder instead of mapping to the local folder

Comment: Does the temp folder have to be inside `system32`? Using `%temp%\aruba-out` would probably work..

Comment: the temp file doesnt need to be in system32 but for some reason when running as a service it is defaulting to that folder instead of the install folder

Comment: added the proc.workingdirectory which sorted out the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default current directory for windows service is System32.

This [link](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/06/29/current-directory-for-windows-service-is-not-what-you-expect.aspx) might be helpfull:

> `System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);`
>
> Use the above line of code to set the current directory to the same
>   directory as your windows service.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're working for Microsoft, don't create folders in windows\system32.

Answer (score 0):

Is your batch script using relative or absolute paths?

If relative, change the current working directory.  This can be set via `ProcessStartInfo`.  See MSDN info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx

> The WorkingDirectory property must be set if UserName
>   and Password are provided. If the property is not set, the default
>   working directory is %SYSTEMROOT%\system32.

Also consider writing to `%temp%` as suggested by Blogbeard.

(post your batch script please)